# Where do high-level architecture and design questions go?

Tags: support, site-policy, asking-questions

The FAQ states this:

> your question is not about …
>
> - **Higher-level architecture and design of software systems**

So, where should a high-level design question go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They go on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ -- the "whiteboard" type programming question.

This site is for code reviews, of course.